# No bean named 'dataMapper' available

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, sap-commerce-cloud

I have bean below bean in dto-mapping-v2-spring.xml which is under WEB-INF/config folder.

```
  <alias alias="dataMapper" name="defaultDataMapper"/>
     <bean id="defaultDataMapper" 
      class="de.hybris.platform.webservicescommons.mapping.impl.DefaultDataMapper">
        <property name="fieldSetBuilder" ref="fieldSetBuilder"/>
    </bean>
```

I trying to inject it in one of my service.I added this configuration in spring.xml under resources folder.

```
<alias name="defaultProductExportService" alias="ProductExportService"/>
   <bean class="com.service.DefaultProductExportService" id="defaultProductExportService">
      <property name="datamapper" ref="datamapper" />
   </bean>
```

During server start it is throwing and error saying

```
Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'dataMapper' available
```

How I can inject bean?

Comment: Do you have the requied dependecy in extensioninfo.xml ?

Answer (score 2):

Class inside `extension/src/` with its bean definition inside `resources/extension-spring.xml` cannot access bean that's inside `web/webroot/WEB-INF/`, bean inside `WEB-INF` can only be accessed by class inside `web/src/` or `commonweb/src`

```
extension
| - src/
| - resources
|       | - extension-spring.xml
|
| - web
     | -- src/
     | -- webroot / WEB-INF / config
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer of @Adiputera is correct but if someone still needs it:

Getting bean from any context using groovy script in hybris:

```
import de.hybris.platform.core.PK
import de.hybris.platform.spring.HybrisContextLoaderListener
import org.apache.commons.lang3.reflect.FieldUtils
import org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext

STOREFRONTCONTEXT = "previewwebservices"

def f = ContextLoader.getDeclaredField("currentContextPerThread")
f.setAccessible(true)

Map<ClassLoader, WebApplicationContext> contexts = f.get(HybrisContextLoaderListener)
def appContext = contexts.find {STOREFRONTCONTEXT.equals(it.key.getContextName())}
//When the context is found, we are ready to get our beans
if (appContext ==null) println "Impossible to retrieve application context"
else {
    defaultSyncService = appContext.value.getBean("synchronizationService")
}
```

ref:
https://www.stackextend.com/hybris/getting-bean-from-any-context-using-groovy-script-in-hybris/

or with JAVA:

```
public DataMapper getDataMapper() {
    DataMapper dataMapper = null;
    try {
        String STOREFRONTCONTEXT = "commercewebservices";
        Field f = ContextLoader.class.getDeclaredField("currentContextPerThread");
        f.setAccessible(true);

        Map<HybrisWebappLoader.HybrisWebappClassLoader, WebApplicationContext> contexts = (Map<HybrisWebappLoader.HybrisWebappClassLoader, WebApplicationContext>) f.get(HybrisContextLoaderListener.class);

        Optional<HybrisWebappLoader.HybrisWebappClassLoader> appContextKey = contexts.keySet().stream().filter(key -> key.getContextName().equals(STOREFRONTCONTEXT)).findFirst();
        if (appContextKey.isPresent()) {
            dataMapper = contexts.get(appContextKey.get()).getBean("dataMapper", DataMapper.class);
        }
    } catch (IllegalAccessException | NoSuchFieldException e) {
        LOG.error("Impossible to retrieve application context", e);
    }
    return dataMapper;
}
```